# Inheritance in Java, can't access subclass functions/methods

Tags: java, function, inheritance, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble accessing any public function in my bin_stree object:

```
src/main.java:

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        b_node <Integer> root=new b_node <Integer> (10);

    bin_tree <Integer> bt1=new bin_tree<Integer> (root);
        bt1=new bin_stree<Integer>();
        bt1.insert(root,20);//insert doesnt show up as a suggestion in eclipse???


}
src/bin_stree.java: 
public class bin_stree <E extends Comparable <E>> extends bin_tree 
{    
    ...
    public boolean insert(b_node<E> localroot, E target){..}
    ...
}

src/bin_tree.java:
public class bin_tree <E> 
{
     public bin_tree(b_node<E> root)
     {
        this.root=root;
     }
   ...
}
```

Comment: @thatidiotguy OP doesn't get the autocomplete feature because `insert` doesn't exist in the base class that was instantiated.

Comment: Because you have made `bin_stree` and `bin_tree` generic, I think you will want `bin_stree`'s `E` to be the same as `bin_tree`'s `E`, so use `public class bin_stree<E extends Comparable <E>> extends bin_tree<E>`, with `<E>` on the end.

Answer (score 2):

No, it wouldn't - because the *compile-time* type of `bt1` is `bin_tree<Integer>`. Java resolves method signatures etc based on the compile-time type of the expression - only overriding it performed at execution time based on the actual type of the object involved.

You should probably make `bin_tree` an abstract class with an abstract `insert` method, which is then implemented in the concrete subclass. Or it could be an interface to start with, unless you actually plan on implementing some methods.

(You should also *definitely* change the class names to follow Java naming conventions. `BinaryTree` would be a much more readable name for the superclass, for example.)

Comment: I made bin_tree() an abstract class. But somehow I still can't access any of bin_stree()'s members with the following:constructor w/:  bin_tree <Integer> bt1;
                 bt1=new bin_stree<Integer>(root);

Comment: @jerryh91: Well no - the compile-time type of `bt1` is still `bin_tree<Integer>`, not `bin_stree<Integer>`, so any methods which are *only* declared in `bin_stree` won't be visible. (And you should still change the class names.)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
bin_tree <Integer> bt1=new bin_tree<Integer> (root);
        bt1=new bin_stree<Integer>();
        bt1.insert(root,20)
```

fails because `bt1` is still a `bin_tree`.

You want this:

```
bin_stree <Integer> bt1=new bin_stree<Integer> (root);
        bt1=new bin_stree<Integer>();
        bt1.insert(root,20)
```

It is also possible to supply the `insert` method to `bin_tree` and then override said function in the subclass of `bin_stree`